# Comparing two strings string builder

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I'm generating two string lines using string builder and I want to compare that generated string with string at exact location (last two lines) inside my txt file.

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("line1content{0}", Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendFormat("line2content{0}", Environment.NewLine);
```

I'm getting last two lines from my txt file

```
List<string> last2lines = File.ReadLines("c:\myfile.txt").Reverse().Take(2).Reverse().ToList();
```

Here I'm getting list of strings with content and I need to get last 3 lines into one string variable to compare with generated string builder content.

Comment: Use String.Compare? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbh501kz(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: What if the file ends with more that one new line? Do you want to consider this as different or should the newline in excess discarded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sb.ToString().Compare(string.Join("",last2Lines.ToArray()))
```